# What is suchness (esp in Tendai or Soto)

Tags: enlightenment, impermanence, tendai, suchness

In [this thread](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/is-buddha-nature-active) I asked about active and passive suffering.

But I'm not quite sure what I mean.

It may help to know what suchenss is? I know it translates to "as it is"... so is that impermanence? Or something more subtle ?

Thanks!

Comment: of course how it is now isn't how it will always be. so how can you find an immutable suchness? or is the principle of suchness always changing ?

Comment: As far as I can tell so far, this is a common mahayana theme about something that is ineffable, something impossible to put to words. What is the world? It is what it is, which isn't helpful, so you have to understand it though directly felt wisdom. But I'm not a Tendai expert.

Answer (score 2):

Suchness means there is no construing. Kalaka Sutta may be useful to know the meaning of "such":
http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.024.than.html

Answer (score 0):

What does Suchness mean when we say "as it is"?

It comes from the fact that whatever we see, is due to the eye perceiving an object and the mind creating an image of the object. If the eye is defective, say colour blind, then the appearance of the object in the mind is different from that for a normal eye.

Even though if we have normal eyes, the object we see is still created by the mind. So what difference is it from what we sometimes see in dreams?

We can only perceived that which is created by the mind and not really know the essence of the objects out there in the world - "as it is" or suchness is the name given to these objects which are inexpressible. Images, sounds, texture, scents and tastes are all we know through the mind.

Moreover dogs perceive the world differently from us so do other beings.

That's my understanding from the Theravada tradition.